# Postdoc in Paris with foreign funding

Tags: france, taxes, eu-citizens, social-security, contracts

I am moving to Paris for a postdoc in spring 2021 and I have received funding from Denmark for two years. I am considering whether administering the grant myself or having it administered by INSERM. I would like to have detailed information on how the salary will be calculated in each case and how to get a work contract and social security, as well how to pay taxes in case I administer the grant myself. I know in other places this kind of contract would be a visiting researcher contract. I am an EU citizen (IT). I do not speak French at the moment but I am starting language classes. Any useful link for where to gather information for this situation would be highly appreciated.